# Can't get the pdf file to be viewed in CodeRunner

Tags: latexmk, macos

I am trying to integrate the latexmk compilation into coderunner on MacOS. However, eventhough it is able to compile it correctly, I can't get the pdf to be previewed in the coderunner app. This is the terminal output:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 March 2019, version: 4.63b.
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
```

and this is what is displayed in the pdf previewer in coderunner:

```
Error: Unable to open PDF file with path '/Users/oyvindholtskog/Desktop/Internship/Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 March 2019, version: 4.63b.
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date'
```

It seems to me that it is trying to view the pdf before it is compiling, but as I am very new to this I really don't know...

UPDATE:
After going through a whole bunch of tips I found a solution.

coderunner is still not very happy with running latexmk at all (it works if you are OK with previewing in a different program e.g. Skim), but I found a workaround!

The default command in coderunner is:

```
pdflatex -halt-on-error "$CR_FILENAME" "${@:1}"
```

However, this only produce the aux files and so on.

My workaround is to run all of these commands one after the other:

```
output=$(pdflatex "$CR_FILENAME")
mv "master.aux" "master.tex.aux"
output=$(bibtex "$CR_FILENAME")
output=$(pdflatex "$CR_FILENAME")
mv "master.tex.bbl" "master.bbl"
mv "master.tex.blg" "master.blg"
rm "master.tex.aux"
output=$(pdflatex "$CR_FILENAME")
output=$(pdflatex "$CR_FILENAME")
FILNAME="$CR_FILENAME.aux"
mv "master.aux" "master.tex.aux"
output=$(bibtex "$CR_FILENAME")
output=$(pdflatex "$CR_FILENAME")
mv "master.tex.bbl" "master.bbl"
mv "master.tex.blg" "master.blg"
rm "master.tex.aux"
output=$(pdflatex "$CR_FILENAME")
```

I basically run a double compilation because it did not actually cross reference the bibliography unless I did this.

I hope this can be of use for someone in the future!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How did you try to do the integration with Coderunner?

Comment: basically you can specify the terminal command for each language. Because the `latexmk -pdf filename.tex` and `latexmk -pdf -pv filename.tex` worked well in the terminal, I decided to try that. The problem is that it works as it should except the "minor" problem of previewing the pdf. It also works when I try to preview it in the Preview app on MacOS.

Comment: Good that you find a solution. On this site it is expected to post answers/solutions/workarounds in the Answer box so they appear as an answer instead of as an edit to the question. It is also allowed to answer your own question, and to accept that answer afterwards. Maybe you can do that here too? That has the added advantage that your question no longer counts as 'unanswered'.